# TLS what is certificate signature generated from

Tags: ssl, certificate, digital-signature

Maybe it is an obvious question but I didn't find a clear answer to it.
The question is what uses to generate server certificate signature and how actually generation happens?

As far as I am concerned the certificate signature is **server identity** (as I understand it is information from fields in X.509 certificate structure) plus **server certificate public key** hashed with some hash-function and encrypted by private key of *root certificate* located on the CA.

Am I right? If for signature server identity is used, please clarify which exactly fields from X.509 are used because I am not sure that used all of them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what uses to generate server certificate signature and how actually generation happens

It is signed by the private key of the signer.

> As far as I am concerned the certificate signature is server identity

No. It is proof that the signer has authenticated the certificate's subject.

> (as I understand it is information from fields in X.509 certificate structure) plus server certificate public key those are hashed with some hash-function and encrypted by private key of root certificate located on the CA.

No. See above.

> Am I right?

No.

> If for signature server identity is used, please clarify which exactly fields from X.509 are used because I am not sure that used all of them.

The entire certificate is signed.

Comment: I found more detailed answer --https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142635/how-is-a-digital-signature-of-a-x-509-generated with refs on RFC